# How to Monitor the data transfer

Tags: ros, data, transmission, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I would like to know how to monitor all the data transfer between ros.

There are two computers connected by using same roscore master. I want to measure the amount of data transfering every second or in a period.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205262/how-to-monitor-the-data-transfer/) by [mree](https://answers.ros.org/users/21205/mree/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are interested in a special topic you can use rostopic bw

```
rostopic bw --help
Usage: rostopic bw /topic

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -w WINDOW, --window=WINDOW
                        window size, in # of messages, for calculating rate
```

Unfortunately it does only support a single topic, so you may need multiple calls into it for monitoring more than one topic.

Also a nice tool for monitoring your network interfaces useage and additional  information is bmon. However, this will not explizitly so you the `ROS-part` of your network load:

```
sudo apt-get install bmon
bmon
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As a graphical alternative to the answer by @Wolf, you could use the [rqt_topic](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_topic) rqt plugin, which gives you a view similar to `top` or `htop`, but for all topics known to your system.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1